# TailTruncation - Ellipsize the text of a picker control in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, picker

Is it possible to truncate long texts with ellipsis in a picker control. I have already created a custom renderer to set a fontsize and no border in order to achieve the following result.

[image]

Also tried to set `Control.Ellipsize = TextUtils.TruncateAt.End;` but nothing happens

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(NoBorderPicker), typeof(CustomPicker))]
namespace Prj.Droid.Renderers
{
    public class CustomPicker : PickerRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Control != null)
            {

                var customBG = new GradientDrawable();
                customBG.SetColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
                customBG.SetCornerRadius(3);
                Control.SetBackground(customBG);

                Control.Ellipsize = TextUtils.TruncateAt.End;

                var custdatepicker = (NoBorderPicker) this.Element;
                this.Control.TextSize = (float)custdatepicker.FontSize;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `Control.SetSingleLine(true);`?

Comment: yes correct setting SetSingleLine(true) solves my problem!!!!!

Comment: If you don't mind I will add an answer. Could you mark it as correct?

Comment: yes of course my friend

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now, I could be sure that `Control.SetSingleLine(true);` will work.

Comment: How about for iOS?

Answer (score 1):

if you are using a custom renderer can be the incorret inheritance.

Use Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.PickerRenderer not Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.PickerRenderer

Tks to https://www.damirscorner.com/blog/posts/20201204-CustomPickerRendererOnAndroid.html

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough, for me in the latest Xamarin Forms, on Android the `Picker` automatically truncates text, but on iOS the Picker becomes arbitrarily wide, covering up other UI elements.

The fix is to set the `MinimumWidthRequest = 1`, which for some reason re-enables text truncation.  I have no idea why. Welcome to Xamarin.